# I have a TypeError warning but the app works fine

Tags: vuejs2

Suddenly I started getting the following TypeError warning from Vue but my app works fine

> [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'Name' of null"

This is coming from a data property named 'dashboard' that is loaded via AJAX call after user selects an item from a drop down. In debugging I have been able to simplify the code to get the warning and learned how to not get the warning.

This line will give me the warning but works fine

> Dashboard: {{dashboard.Name}}

This line will display the entire dashboard object with no warning

> Dashboard: {{ dashboard}}

This line works fine as well with no warning

> Dashboard: {{ dashboard == null ? "Null" :dashboard.Name}}

I'm doing my first project with Vue and have had this code in working just fine for a couple of weeks, with no warnings.

Why all of a sudden do I start seeing this warning?

Secondary question is how do you typically track down such warnings. The stack trace is all in Vue code and gives me no idea where the problem originates from in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Vue team explained this in an answer from their forums [here](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/getting-a-typeerror-warning-but-app-works-fine/39307/14). I'll repeat a shorter version below as it took awhile to get it into my thick head.

A TypeError will be emitted when Vue does its rendering and the state of the data is not yet complete, in my case data was not yet set by the async AJAX call. When the AJAX call does return the data reactivity kicks in and the render is done again and this time the data is in a valid state.

This explains why the below has a TypeError but renders just fine

> Dashboard: {{dashboard.Name}}

The TypeError is because Vue is attempting to render null.Name on initial rendering, i.e. dashboard is initially set to null. After the AJAX call returns, dashboard is now set and Vue reactivity kicks in and second rendering works as expected.

This below does not emit the TypeError warning because accessing\rendering null

> Dashboard: {{ dashboard}}

is valid with nothing to render so no TypeError, after the AJAX call returns reactivity causes a re-render which displays the data as expected.

**Resolution**, quoted from the mentioned post.

Generally speaking you would put a conditional render either around your component, or the data that may require that information with a v-if statement to trigger a truthy expression. As null is “false”. When ajax fills it in it becomes “truthy”